# Array of key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm working with ethers.js and fetching data from a smart contract. When logging the response to the console, something along the lines of this gets logged:

```
0: BigNumber {_hex: '0x05', _isBigNumber: true}
1: "test test test"
2: "transfer(address, uint256)"
3: "data data data"
4: BigNumber {_hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true}
5: BigNumber {_hex: '0x61a4e4ae', _isBigNumber: true}
6: false
contractAddress: "test test test"
functionSignature: "transfer(address, uint256)"
id: BigNumber {_hex: '0x05', _isBigNumber: true}
params: "data data data"
voteAmount: BigNumber {_hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true}
voteFinishTimestamp: BigNumber {_hex: '0x61a4e4ae', _isBigNumber: true}
voteFinished: false
```

So it looks like the data is logged twice, once with the indices and then once more as key/value pairs. I'm extremely confused as to how this works. When `Array.isArray()` is called on this data structure, it returns true, yet it allows accessing the properties both through indices *and* through dot notation. So, `data[6]` will return the same thing as `data.voteFinished`. I don't understand what this array/object hybird is and how it's possible to access array properties through dot notation in this specific scenario. Any clarification would be great.

Comment: Arrays are objects. You can add random properties to them, although that's not encouraged because it's confusing.

Comment: What's the code that is producing these log messages?